# My indexing fails when my grid is non-square

Tags: python, indexing, pygame

I made this program. It finds words in a grid.

It works if the grid's dimensions are equal, but it it doesn't work whenever I give the grid unequal dimensions.

With `grid.txt` as

```
WEDJCIOSDC
PVCEWOMNVU
VOWNRYCOWM
CJIMQPLDIW
QNIEOCMOFJ
FEWMQOPCNE
CIENWMEQBV
IVMENBSPLD
NOEFOQMFIE
JSCNIUSCGP
```

My program colors the words red. But with `grid.txt` as

```
WEDJCIOSDC
PVCEWOMNVU
VOWNRYCOWM
CJIMQPLDIW
QNIEOCMOFJ
FEWMQOPCNE
CIENWMEQBV
IVMENBSPLD
NOEFOQMFIE
```

It won't work.

[image]

My code:

```
import pygame

pygame.font.init()

wn = pygame.display.set_mode((600, 600))


class Cell():
    def __init__(self, x, y, s, text=' ', color=(0, 0, 0)):
        self.input_box = pygame.Rect(x, y, s, s)
        self.x = x
        self.y = y
        self.s = s
        self.color = color
        self.text = text
        self.active = False
        self.font = pygame.font.Font(None, s)

    def draw(self):
        txt = self.font.render(self.text, True, self.color)
        x, y = self.x+(self.s-txt.get_width())//2, self.y+(self.s-txt.get_height())*5//7
        wn.blit(txt, (x, y))
        pygame.draw.rect(wn, self.color, self.input_box, 2)


class Grid():
    def __init__(self, x, y, size, letters, color=(0, 0, 0)):
        rows = len(letters)
        cols = len(letters[0])
        self.grid =  [[Cell(i*size+x, j*size+y, size, letter) for i, letter in enumerate(row)] for j, row in enumerate(letters)]
        self.cells = [cell for row in self.grid for cell in row]
        self.rows = rows
        self.cols = cols


    def adj(self, cell, idx, lstlst, wrd):
        x, y = self.cells.index(cell) // self.rows, self.cells.index(cell) % self.rows
        y1 = x - 1 if x else 0
        y2 = self.rows + 2 if x > self.rows + 2 else x + 2
        x1 = y - 1 if y else 0
        x2 = self.cols + 2 if y > self.cols + 2 else y + 2
    
        adjs = []
        for row in self.grid[y1:y2]:
            for c in row[x1:x2]:
                if c != cell:
                    adjs.append(c)

        taillst = lstlst[-1]
        for cell in adjs:
            if len(wrd) > idx:
                if cell.text == wrd[idx]:
                    lst = taillst[:]
                    lst.append(cell)
                    lstlst.append(lst)
                    self.adj(cell, idx+1, lstlst, wrd)
                    
    def draw(self):
        for cell in self.cells:
            cell.draw()


with open('grid.txt', 'r') as r:
    letters = [row.strip() for row in r]

grid = Grid(50, 50, 32, letters)
word = 'NEW'

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == pygame.QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
        elif event.type == pygame.KEYDOWN:
            if event.key == pygame.K_RETURN:
                for cell in grid.cells:
                    lstlst = [[cell]]
                    grid.adj(cell, 1, lstlst, word)
                    for lst in lstlst:
                        if ''.join([c.text for c in lst]) == word:
                            for c in lst:
                                c.color = (255, 0, 0)

                        
    wn.fill((255, 255, 200))
    grid.draw()
    pygame.display.flip()
```

Comment: Add your exact error to your question.

Comment: @PM77-1 There's no error, it's just that nothing will be highlighted.

Comment: `for j, row in enumerate(letters)` Should this be `enumerate(cols)` ?

Comment: @SerialLazer No, `cols` is an integer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your grid is a row major order grid, not a column major order grid. Therefore, the indexes of the grid need to be calculated by dividing by the number of columns, not the number of rows:

<s>`x, y = self.cells.index(cell) // self.rows, self.cells.index(cell) % self.rows`</s>

```py
x, y = self.cells.index(cell) // self.cols, self.cells.index(cell) % self.cols
```

With these changes, the original calculation of the adjanced cells also works:

```py
adjs = [cell for row in self.grid[y1:y2] for cell in row[x1:x2] if cell != self.grid[x][y]]
```

---

In fact, the first index for the subscription is the row (`y`) and the second is the column (`x`), so I recommend renaming and swapping the variables (`x` / `y`):

```py
class Grid():
    # [...]

    def adj(self, cell, idx, lstlst, wrd):
        y, x = self.cells.index(cell) // self.cols, self.cells.index(cell) % self.cols
        x1, x2 = max(0, x - 1), min(x + 2, self.cols + 2)
        y1, y2 = max(0, y - 1), min(y + 2, self.rows + 2)
        
        adjs = [cell for row in self.grid[y1:y2] for cell in row[x1:x2] if cell != self.grid[y][x]]

        taillst = lstlst[-1]
        for cell in adjs:
            if len(wrd) > idx:
                if cell.text == wrd[idx]:
                    lstlst.append(taillst[:] + [cell])
                    self.adj(cell, idx+1, lstlst, wrd)
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

The problem in the code is the classic confusion between x and y axis, and incorrectly equating x-axis with rows.

<s>Here is the exact problem:</s>

```
x, y = self.cells.index(cell) % self.rows, self.cells.index(cell) // self.rows
```

## Edit:: @Rabbid76 pointed out correctly that we need to divide by columns rather than rows:

```
x, y = self.cells.index(cell) // self.cols, self.cells.index(cell) % self.cols
```

Please upvote @Rabbid76's answer instead of mine.

---

fixes the highlighting issue as we are now able to find the actual cell with correct (x,y) coordinates. In a way this also explains why it worked for a square.

However, having said that, I think there might be some improvements needed wrt the DFS algo for finding the `word`.

For starters, I couldnt figure out why you start with `idx=1` here:

```
grid.adj(cell, 1, lstlst, word)
```

But since, this was not really part of this question, I'll leave this to you.

Edit:: Adding a screenshot for the non-square game:
[image]

Comment: Have you tried this solution? It doesn't work at all. Your result is wrong.

Comment: OP's question was about why the highlighting was missing. I already pointed out that there are issues with the DFS algo anyway which werent in the scope of this qn

Comment: No you didn't answer the question correctly. It is clearly stated that the result must be the same as that of the square. Can't you see the difference in the pictures? The goal is to find the string `'NEW'`

Comment: No, it is not another issue. It is because you dived by `rows` rather than `cols`. The bug is fixed with just changing a single line of code. You wrongly swapped `/` and `%` rather than using `cols` instead of `rows`

Comment: Ah, sorry, I missed that part completely. Apologies, I agree